# How to get multiple elements of a list

Tags: python, slice

Is any way to get multiple elements of a list in a single statement?

I did the following:

```
import random
import sys
import os
import time
clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
clear()

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

print(a[1,3,5,7,9])
```

Which returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "c:/Users/D/OneDrive/Documents/Sorter/Test.py", line 10, in <module>

print(a[1,3,5,7,9])

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Ultimately I was trying to make a `while` loop using this by doing:

```
while element[0] < element[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]:
```

I know I can probably take a long way and type each scenario out but there has to be a easier way.

Comment: a[::2] -> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

Comment: `[a[i] for i in (1,3,5,7,9)]` works with any index list.

Comment: What's an index list?

Comment: What if i wanted to start at a specific point, like print starting at a[2] and print every 1 variable after that as, a[:1:1] only prints 1 @Transhuman

Comment: This should help https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/

Comment: Thank you so much @Rakesh this has helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use slicing in python to access the elements.

```
list[start:end:step]
```

EX:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> a[::2]
    [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
>>> a[0:3]
   [1, 2, 3]
>>> a[2::]
   [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

More Info on [Slicing](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/)